# how to set presentation over fullscreen to show translucent view in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, swift, ios7

1- i have set my view background color to " clear color "

2- and also give the class of my view to -> "ILTranslucentView" ( which 3 makes my view translucent and shows the behind view blur !

3- and also i have a segue which is present as modally and presentation has set to "over full screen" .

these 3 steps makes my view show as translucent and the behind view is blur at the background.

BUT !! all works in iOS 8 + . 
in IOS 7 is not working and showing my view as it has a clear color and it does not find out that it should be present as "over full screen"

is is not supported in iOS 7 ? or should I have to do it by another way ?

Comment: any comment on this question ??

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported in iOS 7, maybe you can use custom segue